# How do I remove quotes from fgetscv() results?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to process a CSV file from PHP, for which I am using [`fgetscv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). The problem arises when in my CSV file I find a record with the following structure:

The line is the next:

> name;lastname;age;"city;gender

```
private function processFile($file, $name)
{

    $csv = array();

    while ($filas = fgetcsv($archivo, 0, ";", "\"", "\"")) {
        array_push($csv, $filas);
    }

    var_dump($csv);


}
```

When doing `var_dump()` I get the following result:

```
0 => "name", 1 => "lastname", 3 => "age", 4 => "city;gender"
```

I already tried to send " ' " as a parameter in enclosure and delimiter in `fgetscv()`, but the result is the same. Any suggestions? The file that process has more than a thousand records I would like to eliminate that quote

Comment: Can you share the code where you actually use `fgetcsv()`, with the arguments? I'm guessing the delimiter argument should be `,` and the enclosure argument should be `"`. A sample of the CSV header and first line or two might be helpful as well.

Comment: ok, thank you! I added it

Comment: You should also add the line of CSV that is causing you problems, and the few lines before and after it.

Comment: What does the first line of the CSV look like? Is it `Name, Surname, Age, "Sex, City"`? Something else?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your fields may not be matching .
Try to print results first

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Example #1 Read and print the entire contents of a CSV file

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```